# Selenium - Why are IWebDriver properties different than RemoteWebDriver properties if they are inherited?

Tags: c#, gridview, selenium

In a webpage, I have a gridView with ten columns.  Six are visible to the user and four are off the page.  To view the other four, the user needs to scroll horizontally.

In selenium, I have a common method which gets all column header elements into a collection

```
public IWebElement[] GetColumnHeaders()
    {
        IWebElement[] columnHeaders = mainResult.FindElements(By.ClassName("dxgvHeader")).ToArray();
        return columnHeaders;
    }
```

This collection contains ten elements as expected. But only the first six contain Text.

So if I get the text of each element in the collection, I get;

text for header 1

text for header 2

text for header 3

text for header 4

text for header 5

text for header 6

empty

empty

empty

empty

Each columnHeader is an `IWebElement` which appears to come from the object `RemoteWebElement`.

In the debugger, I can see the properties for columnHeader[7] which shows as

```
[OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement]
Displayed = false
Enabled = true
...
Text = ""
```

When I expand `[OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement]` and view *its* base properties, I see;

```
Coordinates = {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates}
Displayed = true
Enabled = true
...
Text = "text for header 7"
```

So the `IWebElement` `.Text` property *is* empty.
But its `RemoteWebElement` base `.Text` property *is not* empty.

Are they just not-initialized completely?

Some questions:

Why does the `IWebElement` not get `Text` or `Displayed` but the base `RemoteWebElement` get `Text` and `Displayed`?

How can I get the text for these elements?

The gridView is displayed correctly for the user without any problems.  If I inspect the page, I see the elementIDs.

Comment: What browser? Also, BTW, you don't need to be doing `.ToArray` and passing array's around. Use the `List` it comes back with.

Comment: I'm using the Chrome webDriver.

Comment: I could avoid the issue by 'maximizing the window' or 'changing the zoom level'.  But that's a temporary fix and doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: Getting all the elements into a `List<IWebElement>` shows the same effect.

Comment: Sounds like the elements aren't visible, it's one of the reasons the driver might return an empty string. Iterate through each `element` and check it's `Displayed` property or filter them down first. `mainResult.FindElements(By.ClassName("dxgvHeader")).Where(e => e.Displayed)`...what's the result?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Arran, I've edited the main post with some findings.  I'm puzzled why the 'WebElement' shows `Text=""` and `Displayed=false` but its base `RemoteWebElement` shows `Text="Something"` and `Displayed=true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer but it is not the best one.

Force the driver to navigate to the Element by

```
var dummy = (element as OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement).LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
```

This causes the ChromeDriver to automatically scroll the webpage to the object, which will also change the expected properties

```
Displayed=true
Text="something"
```